# Duplicate usernames in UserProfile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

I am building a site using ASP.net MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5.

I am using the SimpleMembership as a membership provider.

I have noticed recently that there are a number of duplicate usernames in the UserProfile table. For instance

UserID Username 
100    myuser 
101    myuser 
134    myuser 
187    myuser

My site still works as expected as the duplicate entries in the UserPfofile do not map not any records in the webpages_Membership table (so there is still effectively only 1 user called 'myuser')

However, I cannot work out how these duplicates are being created.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide your code for action: Register(RegisterModel model) or equivalent? Do you use custom user and account creation? Do you setup your database with an initialization script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model use CustomValidationAttribute

AS suppose you have model as below than

```
 public class RegisterModel
 {

    [CustomValidation(typeof(RegisterModel), "CheckUserNameExists")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]       
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now create static method as below

```
 public static ValidationResult CheckUserNameExists(string userName)
    {

        User user = SessionUserNameEntity;

        if (user != null && user.UserName == userName)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            if (userName != null)
            {
                User chkUser = new User();
                chkUser = FetchSingleUserFromExistDB(userName);
                if (chkUser != null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(Global.UserNameAlreadyRegistered);
                }
                else
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

So whenever new User try to Register you can check that UserName is already is exist or not?